# Move Woocommerce add to cart button to on top of the thumbnail

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

Any ideas how I can move the add to cart buttons to on top of the thumbnail ?

Ive tried using hooks etc but cant seem to get it to sit on top of the thumbnail at the bottom, any ideas ?

You can see the add to cart buttons on this page : https://demo.woothemes.com/storefront/

I want to move the button so it looks like this :

[image: Example]

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your CSS:

```
a.button.product_type_variable.add_to_cart_button{
  position:relative;
  top:-11em;
}
```

You can adjust the `top` value... But `11em` looks like the position you wish.

---

**EDIT**

You're right! I didn't taugth about it.
So it has to be done with jQuery and a little caculation.

```
$("a.button.product_type_variable.add_to_cart_button").each(function(){
  var imageAbove = $(this).closest("li").find("img");
  var imageAbovePos = imageAbove.offset().top;
  var imageAboveHeight = imageAbove.height();

  var thisPos = $(this).offset().top;
  var thisHeight = $(this).height();

  // Position of the bottom of the image
  var imageAboveBottom = imageAbovePos + imageAboveHeight ;

  // This is an arbitrary distance (in pixel) you can play with.
  // It's the distance you wish to have between the bottom of the button and the bottom of the image.
  // It may need more than 20 pixels.
  var distanceFromImageBottom = 20;

  // This is the new position to give to the button.
  var newButtonPos = thisPos - imageAboveBottom - thisHeight - distanceFromImageBottom;

  $(this).css({"position":"relative","top":newButtonPos});
});
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the position will change if the product has a multi line title.

Comment: Thank you so much but unfortunately it still gives different positions if the product titles are on more than one line.